# Is there a way to edit a JSON file within the asset folder of an angular project?

Tags: json, angular, angular9

I have a language folder inside the angular asset folder where I store multiple JSON file for each language that I read during run time. I would like to make provision so the user may see the contents of the JSON file and edit it. This must be updated in the server so it reflects to all the other users.

I use JAVA for all the backend services.

Is there a way to achieve it and could you point me towards it?

[image]

Comment: You can read the data from the file and use it to create a form the user can edit and send the updated data to server to actually do the validations and update the file on server. However, the file file on the users machine won't be updated until the page is refreshed. Instead of using the asset file, may be use local storage to store the data and update it on API call instead.

Comment: The assets folder is part of the build so it wouldn’t make sense to use that for something dynamic like this. You could simply create an API endpoint for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not edit served frontend files via your frontend.

To realise this you should save the json file in your backend and request them in your frontend. If you don not want to request the file each time you can cache it or save it in your localStorage of your browser.

If you have the file in the backend you will need an api-access point to manipulate and request the file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I can eliminate the dilemma of doing it in the front end and concentrate on doing it with API service instead.

Comment: Thats exactly the way to go.. you should always ask yourself who needs access to the information. If all user needs the file/data then its probably best to save it in the backend and manipulate it via api-calls. If its just some data you can throw away (e.x. if a user accepted cookies) you can store the information in the localStorage, which keeps it also just on the users machine.